# I can't get CGFloat at struct[CGFloat]

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, swiftui, cgfloat

Hi I'm a collage student who made some graph that show how user sleep well. I get date from date picker, and I made function to change date to CGFloat. But I can't put CGFloat in struct. Here is my code. I'm gonna made more sleep data as number of date of month.

Xcode version is 11.2.1 and I made application by swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct graph_view: View {

@State var sleepdata : [[CGFloat]] = [
    [300,205,105,0,0,105,0,205,105,105,205,105,300],
    [300,105,105,0,0,105,0,105,205,205,105,105,205],
    [205,105,105,0,105,0,0,0,105,0,205,205,300]
]

func getDate()->String{
 let datetextFormatter = DateFormatter()
    datetextFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ko_KR")
    datetextFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY년 MM월 dd일"
 let stringdate = datetextFormatter.string(from: date)
 return stringdate
}
func getDate2()->CGFloat{
    let datetextFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
    datetextFormatter2.locale = Locale(identifier:"ko_KR")
    datetextFormatter2.dateFormat = "dd"
    let stringdate2 = datetextFormatter2.string(from: date)
    let myFloat = (stringdate2 as NSString).floatValue
    return CGFloat(myFloat)
}

@State var date = Date()


var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Form {
            Section (header: Text("\(getDate()) 그래프")){
                VStack {
                DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("날짜 선택") })

                }

            }

        }
        VStack{
                VStack{
                HStack(){
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing){ Text("waken").font(.system(size: 10)).offset(y:-125)

                        Text("light sleep").font(.system(size: 10)).offset(y:-45)

                        Text("deep sleep").font(.system(size: 10)).offset(y:45)

                        Text("REM").font(.system(size: 10)).offset(y:125)

                    }
                    Group{
                        Bargraph(value: sleepdata[(getDate2())][0])
                        Spacer()
                        Bargraph(value: sleepdata[0][1])
                        Spacer()
                        Bargraph(value: sleepdata[0][2])
                        Spacer()
                        Bargraph(value: sleepdata[0][3])
                        Spacer()
                        Bargraph(value: sleepdata[0][4])
                        Spacer()
                        }
                }
                }.padding(.horizontal,10)
                .animation(.default)
                HStack(){
                    Text("수면").font(.system(size: 10)).offset(x:35)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("기상").font(.system(size: 10))
                }.padding(.horizontal,5)
                }
            }
        }
    }




struct Bargraph: View{

var value : CGFloat
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
        Capsule().frame(width : 10, height: 300).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)))
        Capsule().frame(width : 10, height: value).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, green: 0.501960814, blue: 0.501960814, alpha: 1)))
        }
    }
}
}

struct graph_view_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    graph_view()
}
}
```

At here I got error massage

```
Bargraph(value: sleepdata[(getDate2())][0])
                        Spacer()
```

Cannot subscript a value of type '[[CGFloat]]' with an argument of type 'CGFloat'

I just wonder that why I can't use CGFloat at struct even form is right. And I want to know how to fix it or how to make it works. Thanks for read beginners question. I'd really appreciate it if you could come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in an Int as your subscript, because that is the required syntax.

Something like this..

```
sleepdata[0][Int(getDate2())]
```

But I think the real problem is your sleepdata data structure.  I think you should just declare it as an array of CGFloats if that's what you want, not an array of arrays of CGFloats.  Although admittedly, I do not know what the data signifies, nor how you are using it.

As it is though, the subscript taken from `Int(getDate2())` will cause an "Index out of range" error for any value returned that is above 12.

**Edit**

I didn't notice you put 0 as the inner subscript, so the corrected form would be:

```
sleepdata[Int(getDate2())][0]
```

As your data only has 3 sub-arrays, any subscript above 2 will yield a similar error.

So in the context of the bar graph call, it should work with:

```
Bargraph( value: sleepdata [Int(getDate2())] [0] )
```

Added whitespace to make it clear how we are accessing the 2D array.

Comment: Oh wow it was really simple error! I have never thought put Int in it! Thanks for help :)

Comment: Sure, no problem!  The error message itself is a bit misleading, as it does not seem to indicate clearly that the problem lies in passing a CGFloat directly as a subscript.